# Why Unable to read Message From "Android Device" Using GSMComm Library ,C#

Tags: c#, android, c#-4.0, sms, c#-3.0

I am Using **[GSMComm Library](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm)** to send and receive Messages (Desktop App)...
Sending Code Works Perfectally..
The Problem is when a message Received , I Was **Unable to Read the Message while using Android Device**,Replaced At-least 4 Samsung Devices , However It was **working Perfectly with GSM-3G Devices**

Error Shows Up at Following Line
`DecodedShortMessage message = messages[indexx];` with Error Message "**Index was outside the bounds of the array."**/

Is Android **doesn't permit to read Message from Phone Memory while permitting to send message**?

I Tried everything that i can,But can't help myself..

```
 private void comm_MessageReceived(object sender, MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                IMessageIndicationObject obj = e.IndicationObject;
                if (obj is MemoryLocation)
                {   
                    MemoryLocation loc = (MemoryLocation)obj;
                    string storage=loc.Storage;
                    int indexx = loc.Index;
                    DecodedShortMessage[] messages = comm.ReadMessages(PhoneMessageStatus.All, loc.Storage);

           //Error Shows up in next Line ,
           //Exception Message is "Index was outside the bounds of the array."
                    DecodedShortMessage message = messages[indexx];
                    SmsPdu pdu = message.Data;
                    if (pdu is SmsDeliverPdu)
                    {
                        SmsDeliverPdu data = (SmsDeliverPdu)pdu;
                        MessageBox.Show(data.OriginatingAddress.ToString() + data.UserDataText.ToString());
                    }
                    return;
                }

                MessageBox.Show("Error: Unknown notification object!");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message + " (" + ex.GetType().ToString() + ")");
            }
        }
```

References Already Tried

1. [Official Site](http://www.scampers.org/steve/sms/libraries.htm)
2. [Code Project Bluck SMS Sender](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/325731/Bulk-SMS-Sender)
3. [Send Receive SMS](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/20420/How-To-Send-and-Receive-SMS-using-GSM-Modem)

Answer (score 0):

yes as i read from forums android doesn't permit to read Message from Phone Memory with gsmcomm you can use a android client to send sms from android to pc by socket or if you have a lot of money you can use androino i see an article about how receive and send sms.

i have a question about how to get the sender and the receiver number from the SmsDeliverPdu obeject because i need the sender and the receiver to validate the sms or how to get the sim number of the phone

Comment: SmsDeliverPdu data = (SmsDeliverPdu)pdu;
 
MessageBox.Show(data.OriginatingAddress.ToString());

Comment: thanks for reply but it is only the sender number who send the sms  but the number of the Sim  that receive the sms i dont know if i am wrong but we should get it from the comm.GetSubscriberNumbers(); and this function not work on my sims because the network provider not supported